# Eject all disks and dmg's with Automator script in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, shell, unix, disk, automator

I have created an Automator Service to eject all disks in Mac OS X.

```
find /dev -name "disk[1-9]" -exec diskutil eject {} \;
```

This works, but I still receive an error message afterwords:

"The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error."

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it like this:

```
find /dev/disk[1-9] -exec diskutil eject {} \;
```

The thing is, at least on my Mac, I'm getting this:

```
$ find /dev -name disk[1-9]
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/dev/disk2
```

What happens is `find` tries to go into `/dev/fd/3` which *appears* to be a directory but it's not, and so you see error messages `Not a directory`. As a result of this, even though `find` successfully executes `diskutil eject` for the files matching the pattern, due to the errors encountered in the process, it will exit with status code 1, indicating an error.

By using my proposed solution `find` will only consider the files `/dev/disk[0-9]` and it will not try to go into subdirectories, as there are none in this case.

**UPDATE**

The exit code of the last command is stored in the `$?` variable. For example:

```
$ find /dev -name disk[0-9]
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/dev/disk2
$ echo $?
1
$ find /dev/disk[0-9]
/dev/disk2
$ echo $?
0
```

Another way using a `for` loop would be:

```
for f in /dev/disk[1-9]; do diskutil eject $f; done
```

Comment: awesome, thank you! this works, and thank you for the explanation of what is happening too. a couple follow up questions: 1) where would i find that error information in the future, console? 2) i have three internal hard drives, 1 main, 2 backup. these usually boot before all other disks in the order [0-2], but sometimes when i have a USB key drive left in a port on shutdown, it boots before 1 of my internal drives, pushing it to position 3, and it taking position 1. i essentially want to write this script 'disk[3-9]'. is there any way to make sure my internals always boot in positions [0-2]?

Comment: and just to let you know, my 'hard disk boot priority' in BIOS has internals listed in the first 3 positions, and then 4) bootable add-in cards.

Comment: Btw I discovered a better solution so I rewrote my answer. I added an extra note about checking the exit code. You can find more info about the meaning of exit codes in the documentation of the command, in this case `man find`.

Comment: I don't know how to make your internal drives always map to [0-2], maybe it's better to ask on SuperUser.

Comment: ahh, so the only way to examine run script errors with Automator is to run the script in Terminal?

Comment: When Automator gives you an error, you can debug it by running script in a terminal, that way you'll get all the details that might help.